# jQuery DateRangePicker - know which instance of the plugin has been fired

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, daterangepicker

I am using the DateRangePicker bootstrap plugin and trying to set the `parentEl` option dynamically as so:

```
$('.dashboard-report-range').daterangepicker({
    ranges: {
        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract('days', 1), moment().subtract('days', 1)],
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 7), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 29), moment()],
        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Last Month': [moment().subtract('month', 1).startOf('month'), moment().subtract('month', 1).endOf('month')]
    },
    opens: (App.isRTL() ? 'right' : 'left'),
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    separator: ' to ',
    startDate: moment().subtract('days', 7),
    endDate: moment().add('days', 1),
    minDate: '01/01/2010',
    maxDate: moment().add('days', 1),
    timePicker: false,
    opens: 'left',
    parentEl: '#' + $(this).closest('.portlet').attr('id'), // this line
    locale: {
        applyLabel: 'Submit',
        fromLabel: 'From',
        toLabel: 'To',
        customRangeLabel: 'Custom Range',
        daysOfWeek: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
        monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
        firstDay: 1
    },
    showWeekNumbers: true,
    buttonClasses: ['btn btn-default'],
    applyClass: 'green btn-small btn-primary',
    cancelClass: 'red btn-small pull-right',
},

function (start, end) {
    App.blockUI($('#dashboard')); // ideally want to make this the parentEl

    setTimeout(function () {
        App.unblockUI($('#dashboard')); // same as above
     }, 1000);
     $('.dashboard-report-range span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));

});

$('.dashboard-report-range').show();

$('.dashboard-report-range').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) { 

    console.log(picker.parentEl);

    // ajax request
    $.ajax({
        ...
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- BEGIN PORTLET-->
<div id="portlet_test" class="portlet solid bordered light-grey">
    <div class="portlet-title">
        <div class="caption full-width">
            <small>
                <div class="dashboard-report-range pull-right dashboard-date-range tooltips no-tooltip-on-touch-device responsive" data-tablet="" data-desktop="tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Change report date range">
                    <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
                    <span><%= 1.week.ago.strftime('%B %-d, %Y').to_s %> - <%= Time.now.strftime('%B %-d, %Y').to_s %></span>
                    <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
                </div>
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END PORTLET-->
```

DateRangePicker Documentation: https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker

The console is telling me the parent element is `body` which is what it defaults to when it's not set so there's something not right about the way I am setting `parentEl`.

Hardcoding the `parentEl` to any selector gives this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined` which I believe is some conflict between bootstrap and jQuery.

I don't necessarily need to use the `parentEl`, I am just looking for a way to distinguish which picker was used (there's going to be more than one on the page).

If this means adding `id` or `data` attributes to any elements then that's fine as the purpose is just to allow me to pass the selected dates to the correct url via ajax so, the whole point is to find out which url should be used.

Comment: have you tried setting 'this' in your parentEl line to '.dashboard-report-range'?

Comment: @DaveBriand If I try and hardcode the selector I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined` which I believe is a conflict between bootstrap and jquery. I am trying to avoid hardcoding it as the plan is to have multiple date range pickers which is why I'm using classes and trying to be generic about the initilaisation.

Comment: have you tried breaking out the ternary operator on line 43 of daterangepicker.js to see if you're getting into the true expression?

Comment: not sure which part you're meaning, but I've updated the question if it makes it easier, the `parentEl` option might be the wrong way to do what I want so I've added a wall of text to try and explain what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be quite straight-forward, in the `apply` event you can do the following to get the id of the picker that was fired:

```
$('.dashboard-report-range').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) { 

    $(this).find('span').html(picker.startDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY')); // set text of span of fired picker instead of it being done for all inside the callback
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    // anything else you want to do
});
```

Previously, the span text was being set in the callback like so:

```
,
function (start, end) {
    $('.dashboard-report-range span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
}
```

but just comment that line out.

Comment: Just FYI for other readers.. From your answer it appears you were trying to use the parentEl to get the picker, but it doesn't work like that. The parentEl attaches the picker to a certain element (eg a sidebar instead of the body) so that it scrolls in sync with the picker button.